# Removing "/" and "-" by 301 redirect via htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, http-status-code-301

301 redirect this:

> example.com/AnythingHere/-/AnythingHere.html

to:

> example.com/AnythingHere/AnythingHere.html

Note: `AnythingHere` means any digit/alphabet/dash/underline.

tried this but not work:

```
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)-(.*)\.html$  (.*)/-/(.*)-(.*)\.html$
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use RedirectMatch :

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^/(.+)/-/(.+)\.html$ http://example.com/$1/$2.html
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It redirects but not to **example.com/AnythingHere/AnythingHere.html** It has weird redirect to something like: **example.com/AnythingHere.html?Location=-&countrySelect=search.php&Select=Account&submit=1**